# Can't process CoinHive in WebBrowser component

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I want to earn money from the user system
I would like to open the CoinHive script in the C # or vb6 component
But my program can not process the site
But when I open the site in Firefox or Google Chrome, browser can open and process the site script , And CPU pressure = 100%

[Picture-1 :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKfJC.png)

But Vb6 or C# WebBrowser can't process !!!

[Picture-2 :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsNEj.png)

Comment: Be transparent and let your user know you are mining on there behalf

Comment: Please elaborate on your programming issue.  By can't process, I'm not seeing anything that would display in the page - so a blank screen would be correct?

Comment: Well, but I want to do this in my projects

Comment: Yes, my page is empty
But the background of the javascript code is
And begins to extract xmr